# Robot Framework : I want every line execution (keyword) to be embeded with timings start/end/elapsed

Tags: python, testing, automated-tests, robotframework

I want to check the execution time on some keywords but seems not possible as the expand button do not do anything not like the failed keywords or with nested keywords.
[failed and nested keywords have time and others don't](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYGKH.png)

I am expecting each keyword to have the timings

PS : I cannot show keywords else I will lose my job

Comment: post the code and not the pictures of code.
Users need to be able to replicate the problem quickly, 
which text allows for (and pictures do not).
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: if you cannot show what is causing the problem, then how are users supposed to help you ?

Comment: showing the keywords in this context have nothing to do in order to solve the issue. as someone experienced with the framework would help